SISSO package compilation issue
https://github.com/rouyang2017/SISSO
Once I tried to compile SISSO package using fallowing command (similar mentioned in the readme file and manual), several compilation issues were popped up.
Could you please help me to resolve this compilation issue?
mpifort -O2 var_global.f90 libsisso.f90 DI.f90 FC.f90 FCse.f90 SISSO.f90 -o ~/bin/SISSO

libsisso.f90:578:109:

  578 | call mpi_recv(xxbeta(mpij+1:mpij+mpik,:),mpik*ntask,mpi_double_precision,mpii,1,mpi_comm_world,status,mpierr)
      |                                                                                                             1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’ at (1)
libsisso.f90:596:98:

  596 |    call mpi_recv(xxbeta,ntotf*ntask,mpi_double_precision,mpirank-1,1,mpi_comm_world,status,mpierr)
      |                                                                                                  1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’ at (1)
libsisso.f90:653:109:

  653 |   call mpi_recv(beta(mpij+1:mpij+mpik,:),mpik*ntask,mpi_double_precision,mpii,1,mpi_comm_world,status,mpierr)
      |                                                                                                             1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’ at (1)
DI.f90:18:4:

   18 | use libsisso
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘libsisso.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
FC.f90:19:4:

   19 | use libsisso
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘libsisso.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
FCse.f90:19:4:

   19 | use libsisso
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘libsisso.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
SISSO.f90:17:4:

   17 | use libsisso
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘libsisso.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

thank you in advance.
Wenusara

Do you know what Fortran compiler you are using? The GitHub repo mentions compiling with ifort and maybe other compilers. It's possible your particular compiler isn't compatible.

There is also this message in the README: "if 'mpi' related errors present during the compilation, try opening the file 'var_global.f90' and replace the line "use mpi" with "include 'mpif.h'". However, " use mpi " is strongly encouraged (see https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node411.htm).". Have you tried this?

thank you very much for your response
Fortran version is GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0.
Also I tried with "'mpif.h' However it does not create solution,

You could probably file an issue on the SISSO Github repo. I'm guessing they just haven't written their code in a way where its compatible with gfortran.
